# MongoDB group and sort type error: is not a function

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections of tweets and I want to find a user id that tweets the most in the collections. So what I did is `group` it first and then `sort`:

`db.tweets.group( { key: {"user.id": 1}, reduce: function (curr, result) { result.total += 1; }, initial: {total: 0} }).sort({total: -1})`

However, mongo shell complains that:

`TypeError: db.tweets.group({key:{'user.id':1}, reduce:function (curr, result) {result.total += 1;}, initial:{total:0}}).sort({total:-1}) is not a function (shell):1`

I referenced the [mongodb doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/), I thought that my syntax for `sort` should be correct? Also
, what's the difference between `aggregate`? Does what I want to do better to be done by `aggregate`?

I'm a bit confused here because without the `sort`, the command `db.tweets.group( { key: {"user.id": 1}, reduce: function (curr, result) { result.total += 1; }, initial: {total: 0} })` gives me something like this:`{
                "user.id" : 1477500938,
                "total" : 1
        }`

Which looks correct and this is also run-able: `db.tweets.group( { key: {"user.id": 1}, reduce: function (curr, result) { result.total += 1; }, initial: {total: 0} }).sort()` just that it seems it's neither sort by `user.id` or `total`.

Comment: group does not return a cursor, sort is only supported on a cursor, you should use the aggregation framework instead

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks. Then why is `db.tweets.group( { key: {"user.id": 1}, reduce: function (curr, result) { result.total += 1; }, initial: {total: 0} }).sort()` run-able? (Mongo shell doesn't complain about the cursor thing)

Comment: Because of: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `group` function does not support MongoDB `cursor`. You should use the `aggregate` method instead documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/).

Should be something like this (not tested):

```
db.tweets.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$user.id",
        total : { $sum : 1 }
    }}
).sort({total: -1});
```

More details about `group` using `aggregate` [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/).

Answer (score 1):

The `group` function actually returns an array.

It should be noted that the `group` function has numerous flaws, including lack of decent post processing aggregation (as noted by your attempted use of `sort`) and it's lack of official support for sharding.

So as @Pierre says you should be using the aggregation framework but that isn't truly your question. You are asking why an empty `sort()` works. It works because of it is a valid function for array handling within JavaScript ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp ) as such it is actually valid, just not in the way you were using it. It also does not actually work the way you think, it sorts within JavaScript itself rather than within MongoDB.

> Does what I want to do better to be done by aggregate?

After the answer above my conclusion would be: Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the insight of empty `sort`.